# How can I achieve float left at bottom and float right at top with css flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I simulate float left bottom and float right at top with the CSS3 flexbox? I want to achieve following situation (**Important:** the text in the div boxes should be also vertical and horizontal centered):

[image: following situation]

EDIT: PLNKR EXAMPLE: http://plnkr.co/edit/oVfbAAIZxRQLRRML7rJR?p=preview
But the text in the div boxes should be also vertical and horizontal centered.

Following Code should be augmented:

```
display: flex;         // for parent container
align-self: flex-end;  // for child div-1 to place it at bottom
margin-left: auto;     // for child div-2 to place it right top
```

(I don't like `margin-left: auto` because there is no min-margin at very small screens.)

**Solution:**

The code above is augmented with the code below and children get following additional css:

```
display: flex;             // also for child box for its content
align-items: center;       // center vertically
justify-content: center;   // center text horizontally
```

Comment: for positioning single flexbox-items there is a specific property `align-self`

Comment: I am just trying now @SOReadytoHelp the possibilities from flex and saw a good explanation here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That's the solution:**

Both parent and children have to use flex. (col-md-12 is from bootstrap and has nothing to do with the question)

**HTML**

```
  <div class="content col-md-12">
      <div class="div div-1">Div 1</div>
      <div class="div div-2">Div 2</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
```

```
    flex-wrap: wrap;  /* is not necessary */
```

```
}

.div {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.div-1 {
    height: 90px;
    align-self: flex-end;
 }

.div-2 {
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/108/

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="div div-1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="div div-2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;   /* is not necessary */ 
}

.div {
    padding: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: black;
}

.div-1 {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.div-2 {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: I've plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/oVfbAAIZxRQLRRML7rJR?p=preview The text within the boxes should be centered (vertical and horizontal)

Comment: It does not work, they are not vertically centered, only horizontal: http://plnkr.co/edit/fTp0swfwY8rCY0kJYxuO?p=preview

Comment: With `line-height` you can adjust `vertical-align` depending on `height` of element.

Comment: that's not an elegant solution, is there no other possibility by using flex?

Comment: Additional html tags shouldn't be needed.