# Float the box elements on the bottom-left and the bottom-right of the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float, css-position

My `.top-left` and `.top-right` are working as expected:

```css
.top-left, .top-right {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.top-left {
  float: left;
}

.top-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-left">
    .top-left
  </div>
  <div class="top-right">
    .top-right
  </div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean gravida ultrices elit sed finibus. Ut sed euismod ante. Integer mattis mi ex, nec ullamcorper arcu sodales ut. Curabitur accumsan massa non elementum fringilla. Phasellus tellus sem, laoreet in tristique vitae, iaculis a nisl. Nullam fringilla pulvinar velit et euismod. Aliquam dictum ornare turpis at sodales. Fusce nulla mauris, hendrerit vitae felis a, convallis ultricies urna. Phasellus eget magna risus.
</div>
```

But how can I achieve the `.bot-left` and `.bot-right` to display as this?

```
 ___________ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing ___________
| .top-left | elit. Aenean gravida ultrices elit sed finibus.  | .top-right |
 ----------- Ut sed euismod ante. Integer mattis mi ex, nec     ---------_--
ullamcorper arcu sodales ut. Curabitur accumsan massa non elementum 
fringilla. Phasellus tellus sem, laoreet in tristique vitae, iaculis a nisl.
 ___________ Nullam fringilla pulvinar velit et euismod.        ___________
| .bot-left | Aliquam dictum ornare turpis at sodales. Fusce   | .bot-right |
 ----------- nulla mauris, hendrerit vitae felis a, convallis   -----------
```

I already tried to also `.bot-left { float: left; }` and `.bot-right { float: right; }` and place the boxes below the content but not work as expected.

I tried to use absolute positioning **but the content text is being covered**:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.bot-left, .bot-right {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;

  position: absolute;
}

.bot-left {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bot-right {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean gravida ultrices elit sed finibus. Ut sed euismod ante. Integer mattis mi ex, nec ullamcorper arcu sodales ut. Curabitur accumsan massa non elementum fringilla. Phasellus tellus sem, laoreet in tristique vitae, iaculis a nisl. Nullam fringilla pulvinar velit et euismod. Aliquam dictum ornare turpis at sodales. Fusce nulla mauris, hendrerit vitae felis a, convallis ultricies urna. Phasellus eget magna risus.
  <div class="bot-left">
    .bot-left
  </div>
  <div class="bot-right">
    .bot-right
  </div>
</div>
```

I even tried to use flexbox using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33756195/4883372) but not work if there's content.

I only intend to place a box element on the beginning or the end of the content.

Comment: you can use svg clip path ,masking technique here

Comment: @SahilDhir Can you give me any example or a link for that?

Answer (score 0):

try this this will work for you just place both divs at the bottom with same css

```css
.top-left, .top-right {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.top-left {
  float: left;
}

.top-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-left">
    .top-left
  </div>
  <div class="top-right">
    .top-right
  </div>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean gravida ultrices elit sed finibus. Ut sed euismod ante. Integer mattis mi ex, nec ullamcorper arcu sodales ut. Curabitur accumsan massa non elementum fringilla. Phasellus tellus sem, laoreet in tristique vitae, iaculis a nisl. Nullam fringilla pulvinar velit et euismod. Aliquam dictum ornare turpis at sodales. Fusce nulla mauris, hendrerit vitae felis a, convallis ultricies urna. Phasellus eget magna risus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean gravida ultrices elit sed finibus. Ut sed euismod ante. Integer mattis mi ex, nec ullamcorper arcu sodales ut. Curabitur accumsan massa non elementum fringilla. Phasellus tellus sem, laoreet in tristique vitae, iaculis a nisl. Nullam fringilla pulvinar velit et euismod. Aliquam dictum ornare turpis at sodales. Fusce nulla mauris, hendrerit vitae felis a, convallis ultricies urna. Phasellus eget magna risus.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean gravida ultrices elit sed finibus. Ut sed euismod ante. Integer mattis mi ex, nec ullamcorper arcu sodales ut. Curabitur accumsan massa non elementum fringilla. Phasellus tellus sem, laoreet in tristique vitae, iaculis a nisl. Nullam fringilla pulvinar velit et euismod. Aliquam dictum ornare turpis at sodales. Fusce nulla mauris, hendrerit vitae felis a, convallis ultricies urna. Phasellus eget magna risus.
           <div class="top-left">
    bot-left
  </div>
  <div class="top-right">
    bot-right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the same as the `.bot-left { float: left; }` and `.bot-right { float: right; }` solution that I mentioned.

Comment: so put your text in <p> tag and then style to <p> display :table. perhaps this work for you

Comment: Still no luck by using `display: table;`.